# Using the NVIDIA OPTIMUS at Ubuntu 14.04/Mint 17 KDE With Wine

Tags: nvidia-geforce, wine, optimus, nvidia-settings

I have tried to use the NVIDIA OPTIMUS in Mint 17 KDE using Wine to run the game 
Counter Strike 1.6 (hl.exe).

The card installs and works correctly (since I use Wine 1.7). But when I try to start game using `hl.exe wine - hl.exe -console game cstrike -noipx -toconsole $ 8 + connect` the the video card configuration completely crashs and I can only recover it by running the command `nvidia-xconfig` but as consequence my resolution is locked at 640x480/320X240 and I no longer can change that.

How can I do to use my NVIDIA OPTIMUS with Wine without having these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install a NVIDIA GEFORCE OPTIMUS card in your notebook:**

- **Introduction**

In this guide I show you the steps to install the NVIDIA GEFORCE OPTIMUS card driver in your notebook, among other procedures. I tested various procedures and the safest one is that because it preserves the native NOUVEAU driver. At the moment I do not recommend use NVIDIA driver "natively" on your machine, because the chance of your video driver get misconfigured "irreversibly" in case of failure in any program that uses it, among others, is very high.

**Note:** In this guide I also approach the installation of Wine. It's almost obvious because the large amount of games for the Windows platform!

- **Install NVIDIA GEFORCE OPTIMUS driver and enable it for use with Wine:**

**Note:** This procedure has been tested and developed with Ubuntu/Debian!

- Add wine PPA:

**Note**: To avoid compatibility issues with the NVIDIA driver when installing Wine use Wine 1.7!

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

- Update list:

> sudo apt-get update

- Install Wine:

> sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks

- To applications that rely on html in Wine:

> sudo apt-get install wine-gecko2.21:i386
>   sudo apt-get install wine-gecko2.21

- To ensure compatibility with 32-bit applications in Wine:

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

- To solve icons problems in Wine:

**Note**: When you need, open the "q4wine" and follow "Tools" -> "Import Wine Desktop Files"! Tesded with KDE!

> sudo apt-get install q4wine

- To solve problems with fonts in Wine:

> apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

- Install the NVIDIA GEFORCE OPTIMUS card:

**Note:** In my case "NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 630M"!

- Setup the xorg-edgers ppa. The xorg-edgers ppa provides the very latest nvidia drivers. Run the following commands to set it up:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
>   sudo apt-get update

- Install the latest NVIDIA driver version ("346" in Dec/2014):

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-346

- Install bumblebee-nvidia. This helps your computer manage the optimus part of the NVIDIA card:

> sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia

- Install primus. This allow your bumblebee to work with your NVIDIA drivers with 64 bit programs:

> sudo apt-get install primus
>   sudo apt-get install primus-libs-ia32:i386

- To ensure that there will be no additional errors do another update:

> sudo apt-get update

- To test, restart your computer and run the command below. If everything worked out will appear three "three-dimensional cogs":

**Note:** To use your 3D NVIDIA card, type "optirun" before the program name!

> optirun glxgears -info